# use of sizeof operator

Tags: c, sizeof

The output of  following program

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int *p[10];
    printf("%ld %ld\n",sizeof(*p),sizeof(p));
}
```

is

```
8   <--- sizeof(*p) gives  size of single element in the array of int *p[10] 
80  <--- sizeof(p) gives  size of whole array which is 10 * 8 in size.
```

now see  the following program

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
 int array[] = {23,34,12,17,204,99,16};

  int main()
  {
      int d;
      printf("sizeof(array) = %ld \n",sizeof(array));
      printf("sizeof(array[0]) = %ld \n",sizeof(array[0]));
      printf("sizeof int %ld\n",sizeof(int));
      printf("TOTAL_ELEMENTS=%ld \n",TOTAL_ELEMENTS);
      for(d=-1;d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2);d++)
          printf("%d\n",array[d+1]);

      return 0;
  }
```

is

```
sizeof(array) = 28 
sizeof(array[0]) = 4  <--here
sizeof int 4
TOTAL_ELEMENTS=7
```

What I am not able to understand is why is the sizeof(array[0]) different in both the outputs.

Comment: I guess one is compiled for a 64 bit machine, the other one for 32 bit.

Comment: @groovingandi int has 4 bytes even on 64-bit machines

Comment: @groovingandi no these both programs were run on the same machine.

Comment: you wrote "same machine" - what is the compiler/IDE and also the machine?

Comment: @Abhijit Rao Ubuntu 10.04 64 machine compiler gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) editor vi

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`int *p[10];`
is an array of pointers.

`*p`
is the first element of that array of pointers. So it is a pointer to an integer. It is not an integer.

`int array[] = {23,34,12,17,204,99,16};` is an array of integers. So `array[0]` is the first element of that array.  So it is an integer.

The size of a pointer to an integer (`*p`) and an integer (`array[0]`) are different.

So `sizeof(*p)` and `sizeof(array[0])`
are different.

`sizeof(p)` gives the size of the array of pointers. So it is: 10 x 8 = 80. 
i.e. (*number of elements*) x (*size of one element*)

`sizeof(array)` gives the size of the array of integers. So it is: 7 x 4 = 28.

Comment: thanks for clearing about  *p what is sizeof(p) being evaluated to and  what about array[0]?

Comment: @Registered I added some more info. See if they are helpful.

Comment: yes your information helped.If possible give some link for this information.

Comment: @Registered the wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) has some useful information on sizeof

Answer (score 3):

In the first example, the element is a pointer to int, while in the second example it's just int. You can see that the pointer has 8 bytes, the int just 4 bytes.

Comment: Lalinsky actually I am not able to understand this concept easily I read and re read Kerninghan Ritchie if you can give some link that will be great.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you've created an array of pointers to int, so their size is 8, not 4.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example the size of a pointer is used and in the second the size of an integer. They may have different sizes especially on 64 bit systems.

Answer (score 1):

`array[0]` has type `int`

`*p` has type `int*`

This perhaps demonstrates the stylistic folly of writing

```
int *p[10] ;
```

rather than

```
int* p[10] ;
```

where the second makes it clearer that int* is the type of the array being declared.

Comment: I never came across int* till today I have always used int *p can you give me some link to what you said?

Comment: @Registered User: They are syntactically identical, as I mentioned it is a stylistic choice.  However `int*` describes a data type, so it makes sense to make that clear by cuddling the type modifier `*` to its base type `int` rather than to the identifier `p` - it is not part of the identifier.

Comment: @Registered: PS:  Plenty of people will disagree with me, but it is the style exemplified by Bjarne Stroustrup here: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html (I know that's C++, but this style choice applies to C as well).

Answer (score 0):

The 64-bit environment sets int to 32 bits and long and pointer to 64 bits ..

*p is a pointer - 8 bytes
 sizeof(p) -is size of 10 pointers - so 80 bytes

Chances are you have AMD64 machine - check this for details (including other options)
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html